build a date based on given day of month
I am trying to below -
I have an API which accepts two parameter startDate and dayOfMonth.
if startDate = 10-Dec-2024 03.35.51.229000000 and dayOfMonth = 25
I want the 25th ( complete date, e.g. 25-Dec-2024 03.35.51.229000000 ) of that startDate month
if startDate = 10-Dec-2024 03.35.51.229000000 and dayOfMonth = 3 (less than the date of the startDate), then should give me the 3rd of the next month date e.g. 03-Jan-2025 03.35.51.229000000
How can I achieve this?

var adjusted = startDate.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth); if (adjusted.isBefore(startDate)) adjusted = adjusted.plusMonths(1);

@shmosel, I'm dubious that that handles the case where startDate is in the middle of February and dayOfMonth is 30 -- I don't know what it does in that case, really, but I could imagine it giving a day in April, not March.  (I also don't know what the OP wants to happen if dayOfMonth is greater than 28, in fairness...)

I suggest getting the difference of startDate.getDayOfMonth() and the dayOfMonth param and use plusDays(diff)

@LouisWasserman java.time would return the latest valid day in the next month: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusMonths-long-

What exactly is the class of startDate?

@shmosel Add the month to the original, not the adjusted. If the original time of day does not exist on that day of month, java.time adjusts the time of day as needed.

@LouisWasserman LocalDate#withDayOfMonth throws java.time.DateTimeException if the day of month does not exist. See Ideone.com. See Javadoc.

Hello ppb, I don't know what the purpose of this code is, but it is an invitation to error, as a second parameter you must provide at least day and month.

@MarcePuente No, no need for month. The point of the Question is to use the current month if day-of-month is in the future, otherwise use following month.

@BasilBourque, if startDate is 30/11 and dayOfMonth is 31... The code is going to try 11/31....

Apply the day-of-month. Test to see if it comes before the original. If so, add a month.
ZonedDateTime original = … ;
ZonedDateTime other = original. withDayOfMonth( 5 ) ;
if ( other.isBefore( original ) )
{
    other = original.plusMonths( 1 ).withDayOfMonth( 5 ) ;
}

Notice that we add a month to the original, not the other. The time-of-day may not have existed when we first instantiated the other, so the time-of-day would adjust. In that case, adding a month to the other would result in the wrong time-of-day.
Also, trap for DateTimeException in case the day of month does not exist such as 29, 30, 31.
